# array to string error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am having trouble displaying `.$app->reactieDoor($topic['id']);` it will show me an error and I have no clue why it does that! please help me.

Ps I am new so if I am missing something in the code please tell me.

Line with the error:

```
 echo ' laatste reactie: ' .$app->tijd_reactie($topic['id']) . ' door ' .$app->reactieDoor($topic['id']);
```

the error only shows when I try to use this part:

```
.$app->reactieDoor($topic['id']);
```

Functions code:

```
function reactieDoor($topicid) {
        $this->database->query("SELECT klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam FROM reacties 
        LEFT JOIN klanten ON klanten.id=reacties.klant_id
        WHERE reacties.topic_id=:topic_id ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT 1"); 

        $this->database->bind(":topic_id", $topicid);    
        $reactie = $this->database->single();

        return $reactie;

    }
```

Error I get

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into using PDO? http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @B3none I did still couldnt find the problem

Comment: I'm guessing `$this->database->single();` returns an array (containing forename and surname) so when you `return $reactie;` you're returning an array ... so you're attempting to interpolate an array at `...' door ' .$app->reactieDoor($topic['id']);`

Comment: I see, I used `var_dump` and I see it now, any tips how to get it done the correct way? @CD001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing `$this->database->single();` returns an array (containing forename and surname) so when you `return $reactie;` from the function, that's an array which you're attempting to interpolate into the string... hence the error.

Since that array should contain forename and surname, try assigning that to a `$name` variable first and use that instead.

Something like:

```
$name = "Mysterious Stranger";
if($n = $app->reactieDoor($topic['id'])) {
    $name = "{$n['voornaam']} {$n['achternaam']}";
}

echo " laatste reactie: "
    . $app->tijd_reactie($topic['id'])
    . " door {$name}";
```

---

It might be better to do that in the function though, **if** that function is always supposed to return a string containing a name.

In which case you could change the function to this instead:

```
function reactieDoor($topicid) {
    $this->database->query("SELECT klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam FROM reacties 
        LEFT JOIN klanten ON klanten.id=reacties.klant_id
        WHERE reacties.topic_id=:topic_id ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT 1"); 

    $this->database->bind(":topic_id", $topicid);    
    $reactie = $this->database->single();

    return $reactie ? 
        "{$reactie['voornaam']} {$reactie['achternaam']}" :
        "Mysterious Stranger";
}
```

Comment: Yes it needs to show always 2 things but can't I just use this code?: `echo ' laatste reactie: ' .$app->tijd_reactie($topic['id']) . ' door ' .implode($app->reactieDoor($topic['id']) );`

Comment: ^ should work as long as the `id` passed to the function is valid - I'd be wary of passing an invalid id into the function and getting something like `false` back which would break the `implode()` is all. @thattommm

Comment: I used the function you discribed and worked aswell, tip which one I should use? the `implode()` or your function? pros and cons?

Comment: The advantage of using the modified function is that it has some error trapping built in - if, for some reason, `$reactie = $this->database->single();` fails and gives something *falsey* then the function will return *Mysterious Stranger* - you **always** get a string back so you always know what you're dealing with. However, if you're certain the original function will **always** return an array, then it *might* be more flexible to leave it and use `implode()` in your output (gives the option to extract either forename or surname as required as in my first example).

Answer (score 0):

```
 .$app->reactieDoor($topic['id']);
```

that line of code give you an array instead of one result.
try to var_dump the result.

```
 var_dump( $app->reactieDoor($topic['id']) );
```

and you'll see it is array

Comment: I see, But how do I do it then?